# How do I specify the location of IIS Express runtime for SharpDevelop?

Tags: iis-express, sharpdevelop

I don't have admin rights on my machine, so I can't install IIS Express with the wizard, so I have unpacked the installer into a folder.

I can edit the applicationhost.config manually and it runs exactly as I should, but how can I tell SharpDevelop (4.3) where it is?

When I switch to the Web tab on the project properties it tells me

```
Local IIS or IIS Express was not found.
```

and the only option I have is to Disable web server options.

Am I missing an option, or is there a (HKCU) registry setting I can tweak?

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not currently configurable. Currently SharpDevelop looks for the IIS Express executable in program files.

You could try setting the project's properties so it uses IIS Express as a startup program. This can be configured if you select the Debug tab in the project properties.

Alternatively you could download the source code and edit the [WebProjectService](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/blob/master/src/AddIns/BackendBindings/AspNet.Mvc/Project/Src/WebProjectService.cs#L68) class to use the correct path.